# Can I use an arrayformula with a split arrayformula inside it?

Tags: google-sheets, split, sum, average, array-formulas

Trying to break apart rows containing numbers like "198,183,158,315,274" by their comma, and then average them out and divide them by a singular number; using arrayformula. It only produces one row of result and it's incorrect though?

[Here is my test sheet, editable](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PYcrjli0NCiChalhriR_etVSH1UPaoIjq_igigUFDcw/edit#gid=0)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi! I posted my answer. Let me know if it worked for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Average"; IF(A4:A="",,
 IFNA((MMULT(1*IFERROR(SPLIT(INDIRECT("A4:A"&
 MAX(IF(A4:A="",,ROW(A4:A)))), ",")), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(A4:A, ","))))^0)/
 (1+LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A4:A&"", "[0-9\. ]", ))))/B1))})
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

---

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lj_cAlcj_mdNsXI7CdgS8-ANQXHYFuBSShJLWsxPn5o/edit#gid=706256148)

Comment: Great answer ! Vote up for this!

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. So you can "teach a man to fish" would you mind explaining what's happening here?

I'm not familiar with using MMULT as a starting point.

Comment: @tlhmode answer updated with some notes. see the demo sheet

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Average";(ArrayFormula(mmult(N(array_constrain(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(A4:A8,","))),MATCH(2,1/(A4:A8<>""),1),5)),sequence(Columns(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(A4:A8,",")))),1)^0)/mmult(N(array_constrain(if(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(A4:A8,",")))>0,1,0),MATCH(2,1/(A4:A8<>""),1),5)),sequence(columns(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(A4:A8,",")))),1)^0)))/$B$1})
```

[image]

Comment: there's no need to repeat AF multiple times: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BirYA.png